# problems with the structure "for"

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    int i,a=4, b=3;
    for (i=0, i<3, i++)
    {
        if (b%2==0)
        {
            printf("%d+%d=%d", a, b, a+b);
            i++;
        }
        b++
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I need help! Everytime I put it, it says this with the for:

> 8 expected ';' before ')' token"

and I don't know what to do, please help !!

Comment: In the for-loop, use semicolons instead of commas.

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Answer (score 9):

You should use `;` instead of `,` inside your loop declaration

Something like this:

```
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because the three sections of `for` are separated with semicolons, not commas:

```
for (i=0 ; i<3 ; i++)
//       ^     ^
```

Answer (score 4):

In C/C++, you use `;` to separate the loop conditions in a `for (...)` statement.

Use this instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You used a comma instead of a semicolon

```
for(int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
{
    //code here
}
```